# Simplifying Fractions with Radicals

Tags: fractions

How would I simplify a fraction that has a radical in it? For example:

$$\frac{\sqrt{2a^7b^2}}{{\sqrt{32b^3}}}$$

Comment: Have you tried combining the radicals into the radical of the fraction?

Comment: It will depend on your standard for simplification. For example, are you allowed to write $b^{-1/2}$, or do you simplify that as $1/b^{1/2}$, or as $b^{1/2}/b$?

Comment: @MPW I would simplify to a fraction without any fractions being left in the numerator or denominator.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{2a^7b^2}}{\sqrt{32b^3}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^6}\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b^2}}{\sqrt{16}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{b^2}\sqrt{b}}=\frac{a^3\sqrt{a}}{4\sqrt{b}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$$